# CodeIgniter PHP formvalidation clear html special characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, htmlspecialchars

Hello I am new in CodeIgniter, and I am making simple php dashboard.
Now I am stucked at formvalidation.
I am trying to clear my form inputs from special chars to avoid attack like inserting  into inputs.

I have form like this:

```
<?php echo form_open('thread/create'); ?>

        <label>Nadpis</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="row[title]" class="span12" placeholder="">
        <label>Slug (url friendly)</label>
        <input type="text" id="slug" name="row[slug]" class="span12" placeholder="">
        <label>Text príspevku</label>
        <textarea name="row_post[post]" id="firstpost"  rows="8" class="span12"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="btn-create"  value="Vytvoriť tému"/>
        </form>
```

And this is in my controller:

```
public function create()
    {
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title-n', 'trim|required|xss_clean|htmlspecialchars');
...etc
}
```

However when I create new post with title `<h1>big</h1>` It doesn't trim special characters and the title is h1.
So what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars` will convert special characters to html entities, it doesn't strip html tags ([PHP Documentation on htmlspecialchars](http://docs.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php))

Why not do this:

```
$_POST['title'] = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
```

Or if you want to apply this to all values in your `$_POST`

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $item){
    $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($item);
}
```